# Can we find a set $B⊂ℕ$ such that an equivalence holds true

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a subset in the set of positive integers $ℕ$.

My **question** is: Can we find a set $B⊂ℕ$ such that the following equivalence holds true:

$A$ is finite if and only if $B$ is infinite

Comment: You've already defined $A$ to be finite, so woudn't any infinite subset work?

Comment: @79037662: But you have the equivalence.

Comment: @Germany I mean it technically fulfills (trivially as B never changes) the equivalence.

Comment: @Shiranai: I have remove this condition.

Comment: Now @MauroALLEGRANZA's example doesn't work, for example if $A$ is the set of even numbers. But what do you mean by "find a set"?

Comment: @79037662: At least can we prove it existence.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Yes. It is a typo.

Comment: Is there any reason we can't do $B=\begin{cases}\{1\}&A\text{ is infinite}\\\mathbb{N}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$?

Comment: @79037662 No reason at all.

Comment: @79037662: It is preferable if $B$ depends on $A$.

Comment: @Germany It does!

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Yes it works in this manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B=\{n\mid \forall m\in A\,(n>m)\}$. That is, $B$ is the collection of natural numbers that are larger than all elements of $A$. If $A$ is infinite, $B$ is empty. If $A$ is finite, $B$ is not only infinite, but in fact it is a tail of the natural numbers; more precisely, it is the set of all natural numbers strictly larger than the maximum of $A$.